# Json Decode PHP

Tags: php, json

im trying to extract the data inside the json file, but its not working, here is my code:

JSON:

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "key":"12 ano",
         "value":"12 ano"
      },
      {
         "key":"12 ano administrativo",
         "value":"12 ano administrativo"
      },
      {
         "key":"12 ano contabilidade",
         "value":"12 ano contabilidade"
      }
   ]
}
```

PHP:

```
$url = 'what.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
foreach($json as $i){
    echo $i['value'];
}
```

Comment: it should be `foreach($json['list'])`. as you've written it, the loop will only run ONCE and `$i` would contain the array that `"list"` is pointing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call to `$json['list']` in your foreach because without it, it will make a loop on the primary array that only contain the list array.